# Xamarin Android, crash when open many apps

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, crash, xamarin.android

Xamarin Android. When I open a lot of apps up to my application( android 4-7 android version) and then go back to application from app icon(not application manager), app crashes and can be launched only if I remove it from application manager. Application has Hockey app but it seems app crashes before hockey launched. When I work in debug mode I also cant catch this cause debug connection lost with studio cause you open a lot of apps up to your application(this is how android) works. All activities launched through `StartActivity(new Intent(this, typeof(MyActivity)));` 
and i set the in app can be opened max only 2 activities.
Where you think can be my problem?
Thank you

I fixed this. I created new class MyActivity and use him instead, where I have a check if app go in background or not, and if app in background - all activity cleared. After this, if i'm back, app starts from MainActivity and all work fine.

```
   public class MyActivity : Activity
        {
            private bool goBackgraund = true;
            public bool loadingScreen = false;
            public override void StartActivity(Intent intent)
            {
                goBackground = false;
                base.StartActivity(intent);
            }
            protected override void OnDestroy()
            {
                if (goBackground && !loadingScreen)
                {
                    FinishAffinity();
                }
                base.OnDestroy();
            }
            public override void Finish()
            {
                goBackground = false;
                base.Finish();
            }
        }
```

Comment: In the Developer Option on your phone, turn on `Don't keep activities` and try launching your app, going back to the launcher (home) and launch your app again, does it crash? Navigate between different `Activity`s in your app, does it crash? If so, you are not handling the `Activity` and/or `Process` life-cycles: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle

Comment: I turn On "don't keep activites", but crush remained. Navigate work fine, and my app not have another crashes, only when app on background and open many another app and back in app from icon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this. I created new class MyActivity and use him instead, where I have a check if app go in background or not, and if app in background - all activity cleared. After this, if i'm back, app starts from MainActivity and all work fine.